# Are the Sea peoples referenced anywhere in the bible?

Tags: history, hebrew-bible, israel, egypt, canaan

To better understand this question. And why i feel this is a good, rational question, i will spend a little time below, copying and pasting everything i can find regarding the Sea peoples.
When one see's how notorious historians are painting the Sea peoples, i think it is logical to ask whether they are mentioned in the bible or not.

**Sea peoples attacked Egypt**

> The Sea Peoples are a purported seafaring confederation that attacked ancient Egypt and other regions of the East Mediterranean prior to and during the Late Bronze Age collapse (1200–900 BCE).
> [Sea peoples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_Peoples)

**Sea peoples partially responsible for late bronze age collapse**

> Several factors probably played a part, including climatic changes (such as those caused by volcanic eruptions), invasions by groups such as the Sea Peoples
> [Late bronze age collapse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_Bronze_Age_collapse)

**Sea peoples burned down Ugarit, and many other towns**

> My father, behold, the enemy's ships came (here); my cities(?) were burned, and they did evil things in my country.
> [Ugarit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ugarit#Destruction)

**Ramesses II declared war on Sherden sea pirates**

> In his second year, Ramesses II decisively defeated the Sherden sea pirates who were wreaking havoc along Egypt's Mediterranean coast by attacking cargo-laden vessels travelling the sea routes to Egypt.
> [Battle against Sherden sea pirates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramesses_II#Battle_against_Sherden_sea_pirates)

**Egypt settled the Sea people in Israel/Canaan**

> After being defeated by Pharaoh Ramsses III, they, along with other "Sea Peoples", would be allowed to settle in that territory, subject to Egyptian rule.

The Italian orientalist Giovanni Garbini identified the territory settled by the Sherden in Northern Palestine as the one occupied, according to the Bible, by the Israelite tribe of Zebulun, where also appears a village named Sared.
[Early historical reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherden#Early_historical_references)

So, any mention of those peoples in the bible?

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below) to better understand how this site works.

Comment: This question may be ruled inappropriate for this site because it is searching for a text.  "Sea Peoples" are not explicitly mentioned in the Bible.  However, your historical references may allude to the Philistines who were sea traders possibly from Crete or the central Mediterranean, or more likely, the Phoneticians.

Comment: Ugarit was Phoenician along with its Ba'al epics.  Thus, the Sea People must have been other people.  If referenced in the Bible, the Bible doesn't appear to use the term, Sea People, But, the Phoenicians and Ugarit were in Northern Palestine.

Answer (score 4):

The most prominent sea people in the Bible is the Tyrians from the Lebanese port of Tyre. Another name for Lebanon region is Phoenicia https://i.pinimg.com/originals/84/10/f3/8410f3f609e5b3385797280ee5156205.jpg.

> 1 Kings 5:1 When **Hiram king of Tyre** heard that Solomon had been anointed king to succeed his father David, he sent his envoys to Solomon, because he had always been on friendly terms with David.

> 1 Kings 5:8 So **Hiram** sent word to Solomon:
>
> “I have received the message you sent me and will do all you want in providing the cedar and juniper logs. 9My men will haul them down **from Lebanon to the Mediterranean Sea**, and I will float them as rafts by sea to the place you specify. There I will separate them and you can take them away. And you are to grant my wish by providing food for my royal household.”

They were experts in floating rafts in the Mediterranean Sea.

> 1 Kings 9:26 King Solomon also built ships at Ezion Geber, which is near Elath in Edom, on the shore of the **Red Sea**.  27And **Hiram** sent his men—**sailors who knew the sea**—to serve in the fleet with Solomon’s men. 28They sailed to Ophir and brought back 420 talents  of gold, which they delivered to King Solomon.

They also sailed in the Red Sea.

The Sea peoples that you mentioned were active during the Late Bronze Age 1200–900 BCE. Solomon was a powerful king
circa 970 to 931 BCE. Some remnant of these Sea peoples might have settled in Phoenicia/Lebanon. Otherwise, there is no record of attacks by the Sea peoples in the Bible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. - It could be noted the Philistines (פְלִשְׁתִּים֙) were 'sea people' who worshipped "Dagon" (דָג֗וֹן) the Fish idol in [1 Samuel 5:1-5].  It was revealed to the Philistines that the just the Word of YHVH (יְהֹוָ֑ה) was even more powerful than the statue of Dagon in [1 Samuel 5:3-4].

Answer (score 0):

Even if we cannot be dogmatic, as this regards, it seems to me remarkable **the link that the Bible operates between Philistines, the region of Canaan, the island of Crete, and a (probable) Sea Confederacy, all these quoted by prophet Zephaniah** (2:1-2, 4-7).

I quote now two renderings of that Zephaniah’s passage, the first from ESV, and the second from LXX:

---

**ESV translation** (**mainly from MT**) with some insert of mine (between square brackets)

“1 Gather together, yes, gather, O shameless nation,
2 **before** the decree takes effect [or, ‘issues’, literally] — before the
day passes away like chaff —

**before** there comes upon you the burning anger of the LORD [יהוה],

**before** there comes upon you the day of the anger [or, ‘nose’, literally] of the LORD [יהוה].

[…]

4 For **Gaza** shall be deserted, and

**Ashkelon** shall become a desolation;
**Ashdod**’s people shall be driven out at noon, and
**Ekron** shall be uprooted.

5 Woe to you inhabitants of the **seacoast** [הים חבל], you nation of the Cherethites!

The word of the LORD [יהוה] is against you, O Canaan, land of the **Philistines**; and I will destroy you until no inhabitant is left.

6 And you, O **seacoast** [הים חבל], shall be pastures, with meadows for shepherds and folds for flocks.

7 The **seacoast** [הים חבל] shall become the possession of the remnant of
the house of Judah on which they shall graze, and in the houses of Ashkelon they shall lie down at evening.

For the LORD [יהוה] their God will be mindful of them and restore their
fortunes.“

---

**LXX translation** (Apostolic Bible Polyglott, with some inserts from Brenton’s LXX translation [inside braces], and some marked term [to enhance parallelisms, or alike])

1 “Be gathered and bound together {“closely joined together”, Brenton}, O [nation uninstructed {“unchastened”, Brenton}]!

2 before your becoming as a flower passing [the] day,
before the coming upon you [the] wrath of [the] LORD;
before the coming upon you [the] day of [the] wrath of [the] rage of [the] LORD.

[…]

4 For **Gaza** will be for plundering and
**Ashkelon** for extinction, and
**Asdod** at midday shall be cast forth, and
**Ekron** shall be rooted out.

5 Woe, the ones dwelling the **measured put land of the sea** {“on the border of the sea”, Brenton} – sojourners {“neigbours”, Brenton} of **Cretans**(*).

The word [*λόγος*, lit. ‘purpose, intent’] of the LORD is against you, o Canaan, land of [the] **Philistines**, and

I will destroy [your] dwelling.

6 And **Crete** shall be a pasture of flocks, and a haven for sheep.

7 And [will be **the measured out piece of land by the sea**] {“the sea cost”, Brenton} for the remnant of the house of Judah; upon them they shall pasture in the houses of Ashkelon; in the afternoon they shall rest up
from in front {“because”, Brenton} [of the] sons of Judah; for [shall visit
them (the) LORD their God] {“has visited”, Brenton}, and he shall return
their captivity.”

The MT (via ESV) makes clear that the Hebrew expression הים חבל possesses inside of it the sense of ‘linking together’. In fact, even if we take into account the Masoretic ‘vocalization’ we may find that the Hebrew term חֶבֶל (that is the first term of the expression at issue; the second means simply ‘[of] the sea’ [remember, 'first' and 'second' from right to left]) possesses the sense of ***group***, ***a consortium of people*** (see, for an example L. A. Schoekel in his *Dictionary of Biblical Hebrew*), tied together to common interests, namely – according John Parkhurst (*A Hebrew and English Lexicon*) ‘a string of persons following one another”; again, according Davidson (*The Analytical Hebrew and Chaldee Lexicon*) “[a] company, band of men”. You may see this sense clearly exposed in 1 Sam 10:5, 10, where there it is speaking about the 'prophet consortium' ('the sons of prophets').

Moreover, this same term, only inflected to plural (חבלים) is translated (in Zec 11:7) with an identical meaning, “Union” (ESV), or “union of brotherhood” (Davidson).

Indeed, also LXX maintains these basic concept in the verse 1 (“closely joined together”, Brenton), using a Greek verbal form from συνδέω, ‘to tie together’, ‘to have a strict relation with someone’, ‘to coordinate’.

---

As regards Sea Peoples they were historically a confederacy of peoples, tied by family relationship or/and by common military occupation goals (I wrote an essay about the Pelasgians ad Sea Peoples).

Interestingly, one of the most prominent people of them was the **Peleshet** (a branch of them were the Philistines). The other Sea Peoples were (according my researches) the **Danuna** (a branch of them were the Homeric Danaioi), the **Sherden** (a branch of them were the Sardinians, as well as the ‘Shirdanu-people’ mentioned in the Letters af Amarna), the **Akhiyawa/Eqwesh** (a branch of them were the Achaeans), the **Tarshish** (a branch of them were the Etruscans), the **Tjekker** (a branch of them were the Teucrians), the **Dardana** (a branch of them were the Dardanoi > Trojans), the Shekelesh (a branch of them were the Siculians), the **Meshwesh** (a branch of them were the Masa, mentioned in some Hittites texts), the **Karkisa** (a branch of them were the Carians), the **Lukka** (a branch of them were the Lycians), and the **Washesh** (maybe a couple of branches of them were the Jebusites and the Hyksos).

The mention of Crete is remarkable not only for the biblical link between it and the Philistine (Gaza, Ashkelon, Asdod and Ekron were 4 of the 5 major Philistines' towns [the 5th town, Gath, was - at the epoch of Zep prophecy - in decline to be considered a principal town]), but also for the hypothesis, according my researches, that this island did work, in subsequent steps, as a general headquarter for the entire Sea People’s Confederacy.

---

So, **if we take in regards the basic concept above mentioned as well as the other data mentioned, it could be correct to translate the Hebrew expression הים חבל differently from a generic “seacoast”** (as many translations do).

Aptly, the *Jerusalem Bible* (Bible Study Edition, 1966) translates: “***Woe to the members of the Confederacy of the Sea, to the nation of the Cherethites!***”

In other words, **it is possible that the Bible mentioned the Sea People’s Confederacy in the prophetic utterance of Zephaniah 2:1-2, 4-7**.

---

(*) The Peshitta too translates with reference to Cretans. And many commentators do the same.
The ESV comment speaks about the (“[…] historical links with Crete”). Moreover, it seems that Eze 25:16 makes an equivalence between Cheretites and Philistines.
JPS Study Bible comments: “Nation of Cherethites, people of Crete (an island in the eastern Mediterranean Sea). The Cherethites are associated with Philistines in Ezek. 25.16. Another wordplay: The main three letters of Cherethites in Heb connote a sense of ‘cut off’ (d. v. 6)”.
NET Bible: “Heb ‘Kerethites’, a people settled alongside the Philistines in the coastal areas of southern Palestine (cf. 1 Sam 30:14; Ezek 25:16). They originally came from the island of Crete.”

Comment: Could "DANuna", "DANaioi", ShirDANu" and "DarDANa" be descended from the Israelite tribe of Dan?

Comment: According my research they are not related with the Israelite tribe of Dan, but related with the following people/etnic or religious group: dAjnjw, dAjniw, Dana, Danana, Dania, Danai, Danaian, Danaids, Dananaym, Danaoi, Danaus, Danoyna, Danu, Danunim, Danunites, Dauna, Dauni, Dene, Denen, Denye, Denyen, Dnnym, Dnwn, Dnyn, Iadanana, Iadnana, Tanayu, (Tuatha dé) Da-naan, that is, Tuadhe d’Anu.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly. Verse four is translated as maritime peoples which could be translated as Sea Peoples.

Genesis 10

The Japhethites

2 The sons[a] of Japheth:

Gomer, Magog, Madai, Javan, Tubal, Meshek and Tiras.

3 The sons of Gomer:

Ashkenaz, Riphath and Togarmah.

4 The sons of Javan:

Elishah, Tarshish, the Kittites and the Rodanites.[b] 5 (From these the maritime peoples spread out into their territories by their clans within their nations, each with its own language.)